# How to eliminate PHP error messages from MySQL calls?

Tags: php

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'xyvz5j');
mysql_select_db('rata2', $conn);
```

How can I do so this so that it won't print a lot of garbage like "Failed to connect" or something (if there's a MySQL error)?

Answer (score 3):

One person's "garbage" in another's "informative error message" :)

I would recommend *not* suppressing them with @ but instead have your production server configured to not display error messages at all. You can have them go to a file for periodic review. However, your staging/development systems should be set to output *everything*, errors, warnings, notices, the lot.

See the [error_reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) configuration directive for details.

Answer (score 1):

Put an at symbol in front of the calls.

```
$conn = @mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'xyvz5j');
@mysql_select_db('rata2', $conn);
```

Comment: @Gumbo, I'm not sure what you mean by that. `mysql_connect` issues an warning when there are connection problems.

Comment: @Ionut G. Stan: I was wrong. `mysql_connect` does report a warning when it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Just check what value `mysql_connect` returned before using it:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'xyvz5j');
if (!is_resource($conn)) {
    // error
} else {
    mysql_select_db('rata2', $conn);
}
```

But the warning for a failed connection for `mysql_connect` cannot be avoided in this way. But you can disable [`display_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) so that the error is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

The @-symbol will supress the errors completely, but if you want to print out that something is wrong, do this:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'xyvz5j') or die("Connection to MySQL failed");
mysql_select_db('rata2', $conn) or die("MySQL database not found");
```

Answer (score -1):

You could set an `error_reporting` level of 0. Mandatory in production code, ugly when developing. So have separate values for the two environments.

Comment: -1 Even in the production environment errors should be reported and logged.

Comment: Gumbo, where did you get that I recommend it in development?

Comment: @Ionut G. Stan: Setting *error_reporting* to 0 is like closing the eyes and saying *there are no errors*. And that’s no option.

Comment: No kidding? That's why you recommend it in your answer too?